# Jquery menu not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can get get my menu working on hover, but it doesnt work when I use mousedown:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Krflq

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#nav li').mousedown(
        function () {
            $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);

        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);          
        }
    );

});
```

Can anyone show me where I have gone wrong please? I want the menu to open up when I click the top-level and stay open.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `.mousedown()`?

Comment: Use jquery.toggle for this rather than mouse down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Toggle` event

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#nav li').mousedown(function(){

        $('ul #items').toggle(1000);

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5brv/

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two functions in mousedown event so use them separately. `mousedown` and `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {    

$('#nav li').mousedown(
    function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);

    }

).mouseleave(
 function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);  
    }
);      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `click()` and `slideToggle()`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $( "#nav li" ).click(function() {
  $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(100);
});

});
```

Also you have to declare your desirable functionallity. All we do is quess now

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqBok)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use hover instead of mousedown

```
$('#nav li').hover(
        function () {
            $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);

        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);          
        }
    );
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nBehC)